# jQuery-Galleriffic, get title of current image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the wonderful jQuery-plugin Galleriffic to display image galeries. Now this works great, but what I want to achieve is to get the title of the image that is currently displayed. If I put the mouse cursor over the image, it shows the title. Unfortunately, I haven't managed yet to get the title via jQuery.

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks,

enne

Edit: Here's the link to the plug-in: http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/

Here is also some code. I'm not sure but I think the image is shown as background-image in the following container:

```
<div id="slideshow" class="slideshow">
</div>
```

I use the following javascript code:

```
 $('div.slideshow').hover(
         function () {
        //Get the title here    
          },
          function () {  
          }
  );
```

Ok, firebug shows me this code:

```
<div id="loading" class="loader" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div id="slideshow" class="slideshow">
      <div id="slide-container">
           <span class="image-wrapper current" style="opacity: 1;">
            <a class="advance-link" title="Chrysanthemum" href="#2" rel="history">
           <img alt="Chrysanthemum" src="http://ulc.local/sites/default/files/imagecache/preset_image_gallery_diashow/sites/default/files/Chrysanthemum_3.jpg">
          </a>
          </span>
         </div>
```

So here I need the "alt" attribute of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the current img using this selector

```
$('div.slideshow .current img')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you hover your mouse over a image, it shows you the title-text. You can grab the title-text with the following code:

```
$('img').hover(function{
    $(this).attr('title');
});
```

If you provide the code you have right now, I can try apply my solution to your code.

Comment: Do you have any code that you are willing to post? It's easier to help you then.

Comment: Well yes, here is the page: http://advancedata.ad.funpic.de/page.html If you look on it, there is a div container called "slideshow". As soon as I remove this div, the image disappears.

Answer (score 0):

For those that have come here looking for a way to get the selected image, not the displayed one (explaination below), use this instead:

```
$("div.navigation .thumbs .selected img")
```

The difference is the answer above give you the larger  tag used to view the final rendered image.  In my case, I wanted the  for the selected thumbnail, as I need to snag the id and name attributes for it.  The rendered  doesn't get the name or id attributes from the selected thumbnail, only the src and alt.

For pushing me in the right direction, I'll be giving a vote to the original answer.